# ASP MVC3 - Marking Option as Selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form that has 2 select boxes (Country and State) that have their available options contained in partial HTML files, due to their size.

In the event of a validation error, I want to mark the option the user originally selected as "selected".

Since the options are contained in a partial HTML file, I am not sure that this is even possible:

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

```
// Inside the View
<select name="State" id="State">
        @Html.Partial("States", Model);
 </select>
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State)
```

**The partial simply contains the  HTML:**

```
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
<option value="AA">Armed Forces Americas</option>
<option value="AE">Armed Forces Europe, Middle East</option>
[...]
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using strange Partial, why you just do not use helper `DropDownList`. You can find many examples, like this one http://peternewhook.com/2013/02/asp-net-mvc-selectlist-selectedvalue-dropdownlistfor/

Comment: Garath - Thanks for the link. That's what I was looking for

Comment: @Slinky you don't need to thanks just mark response as answer